# "Sequence of topics": French equivalent

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, synonymes

What is the French equivalent of "sequence of topics"? Can one use *séquence des sujets* or *thèmes traités*?
Below I provide an example of usage of the English expression.

[image]

Comment: Personnellement, dans un cas comme celui-ci, je mettrais juste *sujets traités*. Le fait qu'ils soient traités les uns après les autres est implicite. J'éviterais absolument le mot *séquence*, difficile à expliquer pourquoi.

Comment: @Damien Merci. Pourquoi pas séquence (si vous pouvez en élaborer, ça m'intéresse:-)!) ?

Comment: @Dimitris Je crois que le mot « séquence » sera rejeté par certains parce qu'il n'est pas habituel dans ce contexte en français, ni même ne l'est-il  dans les manuels scientifiques anglo-saxons; il constitue donc dans l'ouvrage original plus ou moins une petite innovation et le transliterer en français dénote un souci de préserver scrupuleusement l'esprit du texte anglais (mais faire cela n'est pas une obligation).

Comment: J'ai du mal à l'expliquer. Je n'ai jamais vu ce mot utilisé dans un tel contexte. On peut parler de *liste de(s) sujets* par exemple. Ce mot *séquence* en français insiste beaucoup (trop ?) sur le fait qu'il s'agit d'une liste ordonnée d'éléments, c'est peut-être lié à ça.

Comment: @LPH Innovation ? Je ne le crois pas:-)! Un autre example : https://books.google.fr/books?id=dGUlBAAAQBAJ&pg=PP5&lpg=PP5&dq=%22sequence+of+topics%22+mechanics&source=bl&ots=Cn80MQOHVB&sig=ACfU3U3jvxHqgleXkURYpKdfRuUFJhHqSg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwju1YjP34XmAhWNDxQKHQ2GBuYQ6AEwA3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22sequence%20of%20topics%22%20mechanics&f=false

Comment: @LPH https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sequence+of+topics%22+mechanics&rlz=1C1DIMA_enFR786FR786&sxsrf=ACYBGNQsXXWRsxXxL04FmXKpqfjlCRitBw:1574698116860&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwju1YjP34XmAhWNDxQKHQ2GBuYQ_AUoAXoECAcQCQ&biw=1536&bih=722

Comment: @Dimitris Dans le corps du texte, non, il n'est pas question d'innovation, ce n'est pas ce que je voulais exprimer; l'innovation serait d'après moi dans cette partie d'un livre qui constitue le titre d'une partie introductrice. Il me semble vraiment n'avoir jamais trouvé cela dans ces titres, ni en français ni en anglais. Cependant je vois rien qui empêche cette utilisation sauf qu'elle peut être déroutante pour un groupe donné de personnes qui préfèrera ce qui est habituel.

Comment: @Damien On peut parler de « liste des sujets » mais on ne trouvera le mot « liste » que dans des tables où sont rassemblés des élément de l'étude proprement dite (formules, théorèmes, figures, etc.) et pratiquement jamais dans le titre de l'un des éléments introducteurs à un manuel d'étude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my personal apprehension of the language of mathematics and mathematical sciences, "thèmes" is not quite idiomatic in this context. "Sujet" is a more general term and will be the best to use.  "Séquence" is apparently proper; since we are talking here of a set of elements that have to be presented in a certain order, even if some topics could be taken up before others, the definition of "séquence" corresponds well.

> (TLFi) B. P. anal. Suite ordonnée d'éléments, d'événements, d'états, considérée comme un tout et invariable.

Therefore, "**Séquence des sujets traités**" seems like a proper translation. Nevertheless, in this type of translation there is always a certain leeway enabling you to emphasise a given aspect; for the text provided as an illustration the titles below are some options that could be chosen.

- Plan de l'ouvrage
- Aperçu de la progression du cours
- Sommaire